# Is Moon (2009) a remake of an obscure Italian movie Eutamnesia?

Tags: remake, moon

There are these claims circulated around the net that Moon (2009) is in fact "inspired" by an Italian movie Eutamnesia.

I.e., here is a [video](http://video.repubblica.it/spettacoli-e-cultura/la-denuncia-del-filmaker-moon-e-copiato-da-me/116548/114978) which (in a very unconvincing way) has started it. Here is a [site](http://www.3de-signs.com/eutamnesia.htm) which seems to be a promo-page for the movie. I don't understand Italian and so couldn't really dig any further.

So, the questions are:

Is there a movie called Eutamnesia shoot in 2000 or is it a complete fake? There is a trailer and that video above which don't really mean that there is a whole movie and that it was created before 2009.

Is this movie so similar to Moon? Probably would need to come from a person who actually watched it.

Comment: The movie *does* have an [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2665072/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) page, so there's a good chance it's not fake. I'm not sure how rigorous their screening process is, though.
Note, too, that the synopsis is a bit vague, but does seem very similar to Moon.

Answer (score 2):

According to IMDb, [Eutamnesia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2665072/) is a real movie. Yes, the resemblances are striking, but from first hand experience : I was writing a comic book *before* [The Invisibles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisibles) came out in 1994 that hit almost all the same plot points, this proves nothing. I know for a fact Grant did not steal my ideas, but they were **very** similar nonetheless. (Of course, Grant did a much better job than I would have.) I doubt Duncan would need to steal for his art, especially given his upbringing and background.

These types of similarities happen often and influence each other regardless of contact. One does not need to see a picture to present something similar anew only to find it was already done. [Quantum theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) covers this nicely. Once something is observed (or thought) it becomes easier for someone else to reach the same conclusion.

This is not to say NO! HE DID NOT STEAL THIS IDEA! This is to say simultaneous ideas happen more often than most people realize. Given the amount of time it takes to write a screenplay, shop it, sell it, get a budget in place, hire the cast and crew, have rehearsals, do a read-through, do location scouting if it's not all done in studio, production, post-production, etc, why would David Bowie's son try to cheat his way into the system when he was already trying to hide his pedigree and make his own way? He could have coasted through many barriers without talent just riding his father's name.

Comment: 1. There are lots of things on IMDB which are questionable. In this particular instance, I saw a post on one of the forums, replying to this comparison video and saying something like "I'll add it to IMDB". So, it doesn't seem like a proof to me. 2. Comparison doesn't seem that convincing to me, especially in terms of the movie idea. This is why I was hoping to hear from someone who have actually watched it. From those scenes, it is not obvious that plots have much in common, just some random scenes.

Comment: And I totally agree with the fact that sometimes ideas coincide, sometimes people subconsciously don't even realize they are copying something they saw, etc. In this particular case, if the whole plot is almost the same, it would be fine, but if scene sequence and some unimportant particularities are shot-to-shot the same, it is quite suspicious.

Comment: I also should say, I highly doubt that Duncan Jones watched such an obscure movie which no one else have seen (yet to meet such person). Nevertheless, I know about some musicians who intentionally listen to rather exotic tapes of forgotten bands to get the ideas for their songs. Sometimes they just rip it off completely text+music knowing there is very little chance anyone else remembers some 100-copy limited release of some band from minor European or South American country. This is really an unrelated rant, sorry for that.

Comment: The part where someone said "I'll add it to IMDb," is misleading. They probably meant as a comment since IMDb is not an open community like Wikipedia. You can suggest that changes be made, but those are not implemented until they are review by the moderators. I suggested a correction once and it took over a week for something verifiably factual to be implemented. (It was a misspelling in director's bio.) I wouldn't worry that anyone can change anything. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Meat_Trademark I know it, which doesn't mean that it was not one of IMDB moderators writing it. I guess they have plenty of them to handle such a volume, and it is not like they don't make mistakes.

Comment: They definitely do make mistakes (I helped fix one!). I've just encountered too many people who think more sites can be crowd-edited because they can do it on wikis. Hopefully, the IMDb Mods are a little more reliable than posting rumors or opinions as fact.

Answer (score 0):

I'm italian, the italian author's comments and claims that I read seem done in perfect good faith (which does not make them true) and in a very believable, and rather naive, manner. The movie most likely does exist and was shot around 1999. However, similarities seem compatible with chance (besides, some themes such as cloning are recurring in science fiction) and at most the italian film may have provided some artistic insipiration, quite different from plagiarism.